A software testing problem - unexpected results in the limit
Background - the problem
We have two hardware's (HW-1 and HW-2) we'd like to test. We have $n$ machines in our budget for the testing. Say we allocate $x$ machines to the testing for the first hardware. This means we allocate $n-x$ machines for testing the second hardware. Both hardware's have their own unique bugs that will manifest in any one machine we test with probability $p_1$ for the first one and $p_2$ for the second one. We'd like to allocate machines to the two hardware's in a way that the expected number of bugs we find is maximized. Note that we'll find at the most two bugs (if both hardware's reveal their bugs in our testing).

Background - the solution
The probability that the bug corresponding to the first hardware won't surface is $q_1 = (1-p_1)$ and that the second one won't is $q_2 = 1-p_2$.
The probability that the first hardware won't reveal its bug is: $q_1^{x}$ and that the second one won't is: $q_2^{n-x}$. We'd like to minimize:
$$o = q_1^{x} + q_2^{n-x}$$
subject to $0 \leq x \leq n$.
Although this is an integer program, let's ignore that for now and consider that $x$ can be any real number satisfying the constraints above.
Setting the derivative of $o$ with $x$ to $0$ we get:
$$q_1^x \log(q_1) = q_2^{n-x}\log(q_2)$$
And after some algebra we get the number of nodes allocated to the first hardware:
$$x = \frac{n.\log(q_2) + \log(\log(q_2))-\log(\log(q_1))}{\log(q_1)+\log(q_2)} \tag{1}$$
And this produces results that agree with brute force exploration of all possible $x$'s. But there is one limiting case that is causing some issue.

The edge case
Imagine $q_1$ and $q_2$ are the same. We should then allocate an equal number of machines to both hardware's. And now, let's start increasing $q_2$ from here. This is equivalent to increasing $p_2$, the probability that any machine for the second hardware will reveal its bug. This should cause the optimal machines allocated for the second hardware to increase. Until we get $q_2=0$ or $p_2=1$. At this point, we should allocate just one machine to the second hardware (since it's certain we'll see its bug with just one machine). And allocate the remaining $n-1$ nodes to the first hardware.
However, if you take the limit of equation (1) as $q_2 \to 0$, you get $x=n$ instead of $x=n-1$. Where did I go wrong?

You're dealing with the relaxed (real-valued) problem as you said, and that's what's giving you this counterintuitive result. Your model is trying to assign $\varepsilon<<1$ machines to HW1. This is favorable (to the model) because the probability of not finding the bug in HW1 is $0^\varepsilon=0$. I'd dismiss all this as a rounding error, since $\lfloor x \rfloor$ approaches $n-1$ in the limit ($x$ never reaches $n$). Feel free to follow up.
